# C# method CopyfFromScreen crashes after 200 uses?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, screenshot

For my program I need a method which takes a screenshot every half a minute. I googled and came up with this method:

```
    public static Bitmap CaptureScreen()
    {
        Bitmap BMP = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics GFX = Graphics.FromImage(BMP);
        GFX.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Seen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0,  Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        return BMP;
    }
```

Well all works fine for the first 200 uses of the method or so. Then the function crashes at `CopyFromScreen` and it says that it caused an invalid argument exception. I'm slightly confused why that is because the parameters don't change.

Could it be that the function itself just has a bug? If so are there any alternatives to take a screenshot?

Comment: Try to Dispose GFX after CopyFromScreen

Comment: You just run out of memory by creating too many bitmaps.  The GDI+ exception that causes kinda sucks. You will have to dispose them to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @Hans GDI+ usually runs out of *handles* long before you get anything like short of memory, but yeah, the error messages for that are confusing. IIRC "generic GDI+ error" is a common one

Comment: @Marc - memory is typically consumed faster with screen shots.  Take 1980 x 1080 x 4 x 200 = 1.7 jiggabytes.  But only 200 handles out of a 10,000 handle quota.

Comment: Ok thx I could solve it now. The trick is to dispose of GFX and BMP when I finished using them. Only thing that I'm still curious about now is why the garbage collector didn't delete these objects before.

Comment: It does.  It just can't keep up with the rate you are consuming resources.  This is why the Dispose() method exists.

Answer (score 1):

Probably two separate failures to dispose. Both `Graphics` and `Image` / `Bitmap` implement `IDisposable`, so the "obvious" of the two is here:

```
using(Graphics GFX = Graphics.FromImage(BMP)) {
    GFX.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,Seen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
        0, 0,  Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
}
return BMP;
```

However: the caller of your method should *also* be `using` the result of `CaptureScreen` (to release the bitmap's GDI+ handle), i.e.

```
using(var screen = CaptureScreen()) {
    // some work here
}
```